# How to integrate Kubernetes Service Type "LoadBalancer" with Specific Cloud Load Balancers

Tags: kubernetes

### I have a question around K8S Service Type "LoadBalancer".

I am working on developing a new "Kubernetes As a Service" Platform (like GKE etc.) for multi cloud.

Question is: K8S Service Type "LoadBalancer" works with Cloud Load Balancers (which are external to Kubernetes). GKE & other cloud based solution provides direct integration with them, so If I create a GKE Cluster & implement a Service Type "LoadBalancer", it will transparently create a new GCP Load Balancer & show Load Balancer IP in Kubernetes (as External IP). Same applies to other Cloud Providers also.

I want to allow a similar feature on my new "Kubernetes As a Service" platform, where users can choose a cloud provider, create a Kubernetes Cluster & then apply a K8S Service Type "LoadBalancer" & this will result creating a Load Balancer on the (user selected) cloud platform.

I am able to automate the flow till Kubernetes Cluster Creation, but clueless when it comes to "K8S Service & External Load Balancer" Integration.

Can anyone please help me how can I approach integrating K8S Service Type "LoadBalancer" with Specific Cloud Load Balancers? Do I need to write a new CRD or is there any similar code available in Git (in case anyone know any link for reference) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand how kubernetes is interacting with cloud provider. Like for example previously I deployed the Kubernetes on AWS with `kops`. I see that kubernetes uses aws access key & access secret to interact with aws. If I remember correctly, I saw some CLI options in `kube-proxy` or `kubelet` to support AWS. (I have searched man pages for all kubernetes binaries for aws options, but I couldn't find any to provide to you).

For example look at the [kubelet man page](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/kubernetes-node/kubelet.1.en.html), they provided an option called `--google-json-key` to authenticate GCP. You will get some idea if you deploy kubernetes on AWS with `kops` or `kube-aws` and dig through the setup and its configuration/options etc.(Same applies to other cloud providers)